# is there any way to get multiple POST request by their name when running the event.preventDefault() after the ajax script?

Tags: javascript, html, django-views

Here is my HTML I create a form of order id and email . I want to send the both info to my backend views.py/tracker but only email is being recieved but order id is not.Help me please... The above is code of views.py/tracker here my email is working but order id is not. but when I remove preventDefault() it's start working loading in another page.
help me outta it...The script of the HTML is also given

```
<form method="POST" action="/shop/tracker" id="trackerform">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="orderId">Order ID</label>
            <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="orderId" name="orderId" placeholder="Enter your Order ID">
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="input">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Track Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```py
def tracker(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        
        email=request.POST.get('email','')

        order_id=request.POST.get('orderId','')
       
        return HttpResponse(f"{order_id} and {email}")
```

The script of the HTML is down below:

```html
<script>
    $('#trackerform').on('submit',function (event) {
        $('#items').empty();
        var formdata = {
            'email': $('input[name = email]').val(),
            'order_id': $('input[name = orderId]').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name = csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/shop/tracker',
            data: formdata,
            encode: true
        })


            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            })
            event.preventDefault()
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You're posting `order_id` from the page, but reading `orderId` in Python code.